# When using FileStream.WriteAsync() what happens when the method is called again

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, filestream

I am recording a video stream to disk. For this I use the following code:

```
private async Task SaveToFile(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
{
    if (_FileStream == null) return;
    Byte[] buf = new Byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(data, buf, 0, size);
    //dont await here - just continue
    _FileStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, size);
}
```

So far it seems to work without issue. What I just want to confirm is what happens if this method is called before the previous iteration has finished.

You will notice I don't await on the `WriteAsync()` call. I'm not sure if this is correct, but the API I am using states to keep operations to a minimum inside this method, so as to not block the callback internally in the API. This seems like to correct thing to do, simply pass the data to the stream, and return immediately.

Can someone please confirm what happens if the last `WriteAsync()` call hasn't finished, and I call `WriteAsync()` again? Or should I be `await`ing the WriteAsync() call?

EDIT:
I am yet to experience exceptions using the above method, so I guess my last question is are there any repercussions when using WriteAsync() from inside an external DLL callback? The DLL is a third party Directshow component. I cannot verify how it internally works, but it simply provides me with data via a callback, in which i save to the filestream.

Comment: If you write some simple test, you will see that multiple `WriteAsync` without `await` if running at the same time, will lead to exceptions.

Comment: I think calling it from an external DLL callback should be ok, you need to also return the `Task` form `_FileStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, size);`. Perhaps that's why you are not seeing the exceptions.

Comment: You do need to `await` here, as the compiler warning suggests. It doesn't meant though you cannot use multiple `WriteAsync` in parallel, if you really need to.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with asynchronous overlapping `WriteAsync` operations, as long as they write to different, non-overlapping segments of the file:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            Console.WriteLine(tempFile);

            var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(
                tempFile, 
                System.IO.FileMode.Create, 
                System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, 
                bufferSize: 256,
                useAsync: true);

            fs.SetLength(8192);

            var buff1 = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, 2048).ToArray();
            var buff2 = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0xFF, 2048).ToArray();

            try
            {
                fs.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var task1 = fs.WriteAsync(buff1, 0, buff1.Length);

                fs.Seek(buff1.Length, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var task2 = fs.WriteAsync(buff2, 0, buff2.Length);

                Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Wait();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the low level, it all comes down to [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API with non-null `LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped`, which is a supported scenario in Windows API.

If the writes do overlap, you still won't see an error, but the writes will race and the end result may be unpredictable.

Comment: I was about to write an answer saying it is perfectly legal to start multiple IO concurrently. +1. Another answer talks about a different scenario which is irrelevant to the question here.

Comment: Are you suggesting I could simply keep a pointer to the end of the latest write operation, and seek to that position on next call? I haven't seen any issues in the above code in practice, but this may be due to workings of my API.

Comment: @Simon, I believe you can do so, but I think you should also keep tracking the result of  any previous `WriteAsync` operations. Like `this._pendingWrites.Add(_FileStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, size))`. At some point (when you finish the stream), you'd need to do `await Task.WhenAll(this._pendingWrites)` and process any errors it may throw.

Comment: So multiple calls to `WriteAsync()` only has defined behavior when calling `Seek()` for each write? Does that mean that behavior is undefined for unseekable streams?

Comment: @blinki, I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

> You will notice I don't await on the WriteAsync() call. I'm not sure if this is correct, but the API I am using states to keep operations to a minimum inside this method, so as to not block the callback internally in the API.

You haven't shown enough code for any of us to know exactly what you're doing here. However, it's clear you probably need some help understanding exactly how `async` methods work.

In particular, using the `await` statement does *not* block the method's execution. In fact, quite the opposite: it causes the method to return at that point.

The other thing that it does is set up a continuation for the awaited task, so that when that task does complete, the continuation is executed. In your method, the call to the `WriteAsync()` method is the last thing the method does, so there's not really any continuation. But using `await` would have a another important effect: it allows the `Task` returned by *your* method to correctly indicate completion of the entire method, including the call to `WriteAsync()`.

As things stand now, your method returns immediately after calling `WriteAsync()` (i.e. before the write operation actually completes), *and* it appears to the caller to have completed, even though the write operation hasn't necessarily completed yet.

In your example, your method writes to an apparent class member `_FileStream`. Calling the method again before it's completed the first time would definitely be bad; I doubt you'd get exceptions, but `FileStream` doesn't in any way guarantee coherent writes to the file if you execute them concurrently.

Probably the best thing here is to just not use `async` and tolerate blocking on the write. If blocking on the write really does turn out to be a problem for the API you are using, then you should use a queue of buffers and a separate sequence of asynchronous operations to write to the file instead of calling `WriteAsync()` every time the API calls you to write data.

Comment: Starting multiple asynchronous operation isn't a bad thing. In fact it is designed to use that way. Refer another answer for the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623141/when-using-filestream-writeasync-what-happens-when-the-method-is-called-again/28623308#comment45548689_28623308)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you are correct that it is not _inherently_ a bad thing. But it is as done in the OP's code, and it absolutely requires use of great care to do correctly. Otherwise, the data in the file will just wind up corrupted.

Comment: Well, that's a good argument. You need great care to do it right(by not using overlapping range in writes, etc). And we don't have enough information to provide a correct way to do it also.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it appears using await or not in this instance doesn't make a difference in the context of execution time

Answer (score 1):

`FileStream` is not thread safe. Two writes writing to the same file from different threads will not work correctly.

As pointed out by @Noseratio making overlapping calls to `WriteAsync` from the same thread is fine.

So if you are writing to the file from different threads, you need to synchronize access to the file.

On a side note, I would aslo modify your `SaveToFile` to return the task, and because you are not using `await` the method doesn't need to be `async` either.

```
private Task SaveToFile(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
{
    if (_FileStream == null) return;
    Byte[] buf = new Byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(data, buf, 0, size);
    //dont await here - just continue
    return _FileStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, size);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is completely irrelevant. The information provided in msdn only talks about what happens if another thread uses the underlying file handle and modifies the file. Not when multiple thread writes with same `FileStream` .

Comment: The result would be the same, two different threads using the same handle.

Comment: I agree with @SriramSakthivel. Concurrent access to the same `FileStream` object from multiple threads may be prohibited, but it has nothing to do with multiple asynchronous `WriteAsync` operations originated from the same thread.

Comment: Nope. You're wrong. if same `FileStream` object is used you can do any number of async IO. You know, in fact, that's the beauty of asynchronos IO. If you disagree with me, can you prove with the code that throws exception with single `FileStream` instance?

Comment: The OP didn't specify same thread, so I guess I made an assumption it could be from different threads,

Comment: You can use multiple threads also (which won't fail if async calls are not interleaving). But with single thread you can start multiple asynchronous IO simultaneously without any problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, just a minor correct, `FileStream` can indeed be accessed from multiple threads, but not concurrently. I.e., a `lock` mechanism needs to be used, as with many other .NET classes. That includes `WriteAsync`, but just the method call itself, rather than the whole duration of the asynchronous operation.

Comment: @Noseratio yes you're right. That's what I was trying to explain with the sentence *if async calls are not interleaving* but you did it better.