Is it possible to call WriteAsync multiple times at once?
I want to do something like this
byte[] b1,b2,b3,...
task1=fs.WriteAsync(b1, 0, b1.Length);
task2=fs.WriteAsync(b2, 0, b2.Length);
task3=fs.WriteAsync(b3, 0, b3.Length);
...
Task.WaitAll(task1,task2,task3,...)

However, I think there is a problem, unless fs is in append mode.
It all depends on whether WriteAsync updates file position before or after it returns its task.
If it updates file pointer before awaiting the syscall, like the pseudocode of old WriteAsync from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/file-io-improvements-in-dotnet-6/
async ValueTask WriteAsyncBefore(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer)
{
    long oldEndOfFile = GetFileLength(_handle); // 1st sys-call
    long newEndOfFile = _position + buffer.Length;

    if (newEndOfFile > oldEndOfFile) // this was true for EVERY write to an empty file
    {
        ExtendTheFile(_handle, newEndOfFile); // 2nd sys-call

        SetFilePosition(_handle, newEndOfFile); // 3rd sys-call
        _position += buffer.Length;
    }

    await WriteFile(_handle, buffer); // 4th sys-call
}

there will be no issue, since each WriteAsync is able to use the correct +=ed position from the previous one.
However, the more likely situation is that WriteAsync changes filepos after WriteFile, causing race condition, such as the new WriteAsync:
async ValueTask WriteAsyncAfter(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer)
{
    await WriteFile(_handle, buffer, _position); // the ONLY sys-call
    _position += buffer.Length;
}

Manually setting filepos is of no help:
pos=0;
fs.Seek(pos,Begin);
task1=fs.WriteAsync(b1, 0, b1.Length);
pos+=b1.Length;
fs.Seek(pos,Begin);
//what if the prev WriteAsync completes and changes file position at this moment?
task2=fs.WriteAsync(b2, 0, b2.Length);
pos+=b2.Length;
fs.Seek(pos,Begin);
//same problem
task3=fs.WriteAsync(b3, 0, b3.Length);


Why would you want to do that?

similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623141/when-using-filestream-writeasync-what-happens-when-the-method-is-called-again
Data are received from 3rd party lib via callback.
I want to save them to file without blocking the callback thread, avoiding writing dedicated writer thread&queue when possible.

Didn't that article tell you to use the RandomAccess class to write?

I want to be compatible with .net framework, so RandomAccess is not considered.

Looking at the source code. it seems thread safe: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs

That's not going to end well, use a MemoryStream

Or better: a queue, with a single async task that dequeues.

No. The outcome of this is undefined - if you're lucky it'll throw an exception of some kind; if you're not lucky it'll just silently create random corruption to your data (not necessarily immediately; a few tests that pass by chance do not mean that this usage is valid). This API allows a single operation at a time - synchronous or asynchronous. In the case of asynchronous: the previous operation must be fully awaited before the next operation is started.
Note that the exact specifics are dependent on the underlying stream - for example, the NetworkStream API (also a Stream, like FileStream is a Stream) is duplex and allows one read operation (of any kind) and one write operation at a time (it is essentially two completely indepenent streams sharing a single wrapper); most Stream implementations however, only allow a single concurrent operation at all.
